# Google map not displaying? Cordova plugin

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have followed the following link instructions just test that a map is appearing. So I got to stage 4 where the map should be displayed, however I am not getting anything. (http://www.christianengvall.se/phonegap-and-google-maps/)

I have added all the references for the JS and CSS files, as well as installing the google map plugin.

I changed the function ondeviceready as I am already using this function for other code, so instead the map should initialize when the submit button is clicked. The reason for this is because I keep all my JavaScript outside the HTML page and on a specific JS file.

So at the moment, when i clicked the button, nothing is happening. 
Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="map" data-theme="d">
<div data-role="content">
    <input type="submit" value="View Map" onclick="return mapAPI()">
<div id="map_canvas">
</div>
    </div>
```

mapAPI function:

```
function mapAPI(){
var map = new GoogleMap();
map.initialize();
```

}

googlemap.js:

```
function GoogleMap(){
  this.initialize = function(){
   var map = showMap();
 }
  var showMap = function(){
  var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 4,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
return map;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

[Attach](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#DomEvents) an event listener to the button instead.

```
<input type="submit" id="viewMap" value="View Map">

<script>
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('viewMap'), 'click', mapAPI);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the above, I put the event listener within the html page but the button does not do anything. Any other ideas?

Comment: Do I have to have an API key?

Comment: Put the `script` tag for the event listener in right before the closing `body` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Are you whitelisting the URL in the Head section of the index.html.
If not , this is how you do it .

```
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com/ https://maps.gstatic.com/ https://mts0.googleapis.com/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

A simple way to show googlemaps on the mobile using Cordova

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    }



</script>
```

You need API KEY for Googlemaps to work , Generate one and put the reference head section

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```